# python - Is it a bad practice to do I/O in unitest

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have some unitest is doing something like:

```
_files = ('test1.txt','test2.txt'......)
setUp(){
    //create test files

    for f in _files:
        f = open(f, 'w')
        f.close()
}
tearDown(){
    for f in _files:
    if os.path.exists(f):
        os.remove(f)
}
```

But some people told me it's not a good practice to do I/O in unitest, is it true?

Comment: Well, it's not inexcusable, but I'd say you do need a good reason. What's your justification for pulling in the entire I/O machinery and making your tests depend on the location and contents of non-source files?

Comment: It would be pretty hard to do logging if you were never supposed to do I/O in tests.  I would echo @delnan in saying it really depends upon what you are using the I/O for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But some people told me it's not a good practice to do I/O in unitest, is it true?

I don't think it's necessarily bad to perform I/O in a unit test.

The only caveat is that if your unit test relies on some pre-existing data files in order to do its thing, then the files should be considered part of the unit test (and therefore version controlled etc).

P.S. Have you tried asking those who gave you this advice for specific reasons behind the recommendation?

Answer (score 0):

In general, its best practice to write your tests so that they fail only when the expected behavior is not being produced.

If you include any third party code, or logic other than your method-to-test, you are adding reasons for the test to fail even if the method-to-test works fine. In unit testing, you use mocks to substitute other objects or methods and therefore replace any logic you do not want to test. This helps to keep the test actually covering only a unit of code.

If your test connects to a database, reads and writes files, GETs from a web service, etc., then it is probably really an integration test. Integration tests are very useful, since you can detect problems that unit tests fail to identify. But the upside of unit tests is that if a well written unit test fails, you already know what part of the code has the problem, what is the expected behavior and what is happening instead.

When reading input files, the files become part of the test, so now you have the test split in two locations. Anyone who wants to understand the test might need to open the file and take a look at it, you need to add the file to source control, etc. If the file is short, then its better to just mock I/O functions to have the test in one place.